# How to install PHP 8.1 on Amazon Linux 2 (ARM64)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, arm, php-8.1

I'm trying to install php 8.1 on a Graviton 2 (ARM64) EC2 instance thats running Amazon Linux 2.

All of the guides I've followed use `remi-release-7.rpm`. When I use this repository, yum updates are flooded with 404 errors like

```
http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/safe/aarch64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
```

Is there a relatively easy way to install PHP 8.1 on this type of instance?

Comment: "remi" repository is only forx86_64, no ARM build yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can build it from source. I was able to install it on Amazon Linux 2 on Graviton (aarch64, 5.10 kernel) using the steps below. Be sure to update the url in the wget command to the latest available version or what ever you want to build.

```
sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools" "Development Libraries"
sudo yum -y install libxml2-devel sqlite-devel
wget https://www.php.net/distributions/php-8.1.5.tar.xz
tar -xf php-8.1.5.tar.xz
cd php-8.1.5/
./configure
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make -j$(nproc) install
```

Alternatively, you could just use a container. You can get one from Amazon ECR here: https://gallery.ecr.aws/docker/library/php

```
docker pull public.ecr.aws/docker/library/php:8.1-rc-apache-bullseye
```

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Linux 2 now has built-in support for PHP 8.1 including ARM!

https://repost.aws/questions/QUsfhDbww4SAy8i5Jmd4vcMg/amazon-linux-2-amazon-linux-extras-php-8-1-support